# Why am I getting "Activator not found" when starting my service?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, felix-dependency-manager

I wrote a test class for OSGi Felix framework testing. The class is as follows:

```
package tutorial.example2.service;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

@Override
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    props.put("Language", "English");
    context.registerService(DictionaryService.class.getName(),
            new DictionaryImpl(), props);

}

@Override
public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private static class DictionaryImpl implements DictionaryService {
    String[] m_dictionary = { "welcome", "to", "the", "osgi", "tutorial" };

    public boolean checkWord(String word) {
        word = word.toLowerCase();

        for (int i = 0; i < m_dictionary.length; i++) {
            if (m_dictionary[i].equals(word)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

}
```

Following is my manifest.mf file:

```
Bundle-Name: English dictionary
Bundle-Description: A bundle that registers an English dictionary service
Bundle-Vendor: Apache Felix
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-Activator: tutorial.example2.service.Activator
Export-Package: tutorial.example2.service
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework
```

Then I used the following 2 commands to compile the classes and generate the bundle jar file.

```
javac -cp C:\Users\user\Desktop\felix-framework-4.0.3\bin\felix.jar *.java   service\*.java
jar cfm producer.jar manifest_producer.mf -C C:\Users\kavin\Desktop \assignment2\producer
```

Then I logged into OSGi and when I start the service using the following command,

```
start file:/C:/Users/user/Desktop/assignment2/producer.jar
```

It gives a BundleException:Not Found activator class. Exception is as follows:

```
g! start file:/C:/Users/mayooranM/Desktop/TESTWS/Example2/src/tutorial/example2/
```

service/example.jar

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Not found: tutorial.example2.service.Activat
or
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.createBundleActivator(Felix.java:417
5)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1972)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1895)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:944)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.command.Basic.start(Basic.java:729)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.invoke(Reflective.java:137)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:
82)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:477)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:4
03)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessi
onImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Console.run(Console.java:62)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Shell.console(Shell.java:203)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Shell.gosh(Shell.java:128)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.invoke(Reflective.java:137)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:
82)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:477)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:4
03)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessi
onImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Activator.run(Activator.java:75)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tutorial.example2.service.Activator
 not found by [95]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDele
gation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1460)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringIm
pl.java:72)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadCla
ss(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.getClassByDelegation(Bund
leWiringImpl.java:1317)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.createBundleActivator(Felix.java:417
0)
        ... 33 more
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tutorial.example2.service.Activator not found
```

by [95]

Why am I getting that error? please advice.

Comment: Could you please upload the generated jar to somewhere and put a link here?

Comment: I'm sure your jar artifact is just missing your manifest entries, try to check those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that your classes anre't correctly packaged within your JAR file. The MANIFEST file is correclty configured and you use the correct option in the jar command to add it within your jar file.

I recommend you to use more advanced build system to build your project like Ant or Maven. Here is a sample `build.xml` file for Ant. Perhaps can you make a try with it to see if it fixes your problem.

```
<project name="My project" default="package" basedir=".">
    <description>My project</description>
    <property name="bin.dir" location="bin"/>
    <property name="src.dir" location="src"/>
    <property name="libs.dir" location="(the folder where my jar are)"/>

    <path id="src">
        <pathelement location="${src.dir}"/>
    </path>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${bin.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${bin.dir}/META-INF"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${bin.dir}" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" source="1.7"  target="1.7">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="${libs.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*.jar" />
                </fileset>
            </classpath>
        </javac>
        <copy todir="${bin.dir}/META-INF">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}/META-INF"/>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="package" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${basedir}/target"/>
        <delete file="${basedir}/target/myjarfile.jar" />
        <zip destfile="${basedir}/target/myjarfile.jar"
             basedir="${bin.dir}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry